# I have a list of 100K items to process. How to process this in concurrent manner using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have list of 100000 items that needs to be posted to a URL end point.
If I were to process this sequentially, performance wise, this would be a long wait. Would this be solved via parallel process or concurrent future? Obviously each element in the list can only be posted once. Do I need to track the threads?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You probably want a pool of threads (take a look at `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: Did you look into Celery? Which uses a task queue to manage python tasks in parallel. I know, you can do this with vanilla Python threads. But Celery helps you with management (at the cost of a small overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks IO bound, not CPU bound, so you may get nice performances by using [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and use [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to wait them all to complete.